# Let k be an odd prime. Show that $n^2 + (n + 1)^2 = km^2$ is possible only when $−1$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod k$.​

Tags: number-theory

Let k be an odd prime. Show that $n^2 + (n + 1)^2 = km^2$ is possible only when $−1$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod k$

Number Theory Question！I need help! I know I need to relate quadratic modular -1 to mod 4. But I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: There is a solution when you can provide $k$ to a sum of two squares.  $k=a^2+b^2$

Comment: The discriminant of the quadratic $n^2 + (n + 1)^2$ is $\Delta=-4$ and so there is a solution of $n^2 + (n + 1)^2 \equiv 0 \bmod k$ iff $-1$ has a square root mod $k$. Only remains to prove that we can take the quotient a square.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod k$ iff $k\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Reduce $\pmod 4$.

$n$ is either even or odd, either way, the left hand is $1\pmod 4$.  If $m$ is even, the equality is clearly impossible.  It follows that $m^2$ is $1\pmod 4$ and your desired result follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the solution for the equation.

$$n^2+(n+1)^2=km^2$$

You can record via the solution of the equation Pell.

$$p^2-2ks^2=-1$$

So.

$$n=\frac{p-1}{2}$$

$$m=s$$